# Build Kobold2d project from command line

Tags: xcode4, kobold2d

I posted this on the Kobold2d forums but haven't received any replies yet. I'm hoping the larger audience here at SO can help.

I'm trying to get our Kobold2d project working with our Hudson CI server. I'd like to have a script that executes the proper command line build instructions using xcodebuild, but I'm running into a problem with any Kobold2d project.

As a test I created a Orthogonal-Tilemap template project and built/ran it in the xcode 4.4.1 gui successfully. Building the projects individually from the command line the Kobold2D-Libraries.xcodeproj reports a successful build (though I have no idea where any products are stored), but the tilemap project fails with the message:

`ld: file not found: <path>/Kobold2D/Kobold2D-2.0.3/BuildTest/build/Release-iphoneos/libkobold2d-ios.a`

The only information I can find on this message talks about errors from building in the xcode gui, which is not the problem.

I also tried having xcodebuild build the workspace file but that failed with multiple dependency errors.

Has anyone found a way to successfully build Kobold2d projects from the command line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I use Hudson to automate Kobold2D builds. Here's the [build script for Hudson](https://github.com/kobold2d/Kobold2D/blob/master/BuildManagement/hudson-build.sh).

I can see from your path that you changed Xcode's default build locations (Advanced, next to Derived Data in Preferences -> Locations). There's one setting (legacy) that doesn't work at all with Kobold2D, and should actually open a browser window explaining the issue should you have used that setting.

I think your setting is "relative to project" or something similar. Try changing the build location to Xcode default (Unique) and try again. You can use a custom location for derived data if you want to.

In any case, if the output location path of build products ends up being somewhere in the app project folder (in this case: BuildTest) then ld won't be able to find dependencies because they're not all in the same folder. If you do require this you could add a pre-link step that copies the .a files to the correct location. But it's best to avoid this because it'll be prone to breaking.

Comment: Great info and thanks for the response! I didn't intentionally change the xcode build location, but I do see the place you mention and it's set to 'Unique' right now, so I'll look into that. I'll also check out the build script and see if I can adapt that to make it work. Once I get it going I'll come back with more info and mark this as my answer. Thanks again! :-)

Answer (score 0):

My script includes

```
xcodebuild -workspace Bulge.xcworkspace -scheme Bulge-iOS -sdk ${sdk} archive || die "Archive failed"
```